# Is there a universal constructional difference between Rogowski coils and current transformers?

Tags: transformer, current-measurement

In terms of application, Rogowski coils are unloaded whereas CTs are used heavily loaded. But this is just a difference in the surrounding circuit.

I think, CTs need much higher inductance to provide their short circuit current through any reasonable burden resistor, so they would be costlier, whereas the Rogowski approach saves costs on the coil but needs the additional intergrator.

Do the names "Rogowski coil" and "current transformer" have any implications for how the coil is made? Or can I use one as the other by changing the circuit, and it is just about a tradeoff between costs for the coil and costs for the surrounding circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rogowski coil is not intended to be a transformer, it's used to measure the magnetic field or actually it's line integral around a wire or in a magnetic circuit. The output voltage is proportional to the changing rate of the current if the coil is around a wire which has current. In theory this makes possible even a clamp type DC current meter - the change happens when the clamp is placed around the wire and the pulse from the coil is caught to an integrator.

The function of the R.coil as a wire current measuring tool can be explained with the induction law u = M(di/dt) where M is the mutual inductance, u is the coil output voltage and i is the current in a wire. A deeper analysis which shows the effect (or actually no-effect) of the exact placement of the coil needs magnetic vector field equations and the Stokes integration law. This all needs knowledge of 1st year university level engineering math, so I skip it.

Comment: if you replace "rogowski coil" in your answer with CT, it is equally valid. You could also not use a burden, and instead integrate the voltage..What gives?

Comment: They are NOT the same. Current transformer can work as Rogowski coil, a coreless  coil which works as R.coil cannot be a practical current transformer due low magnetic coupling.

Comment: Ah ok so they difference is in coupling. Because the CT secondary is loaded, it actually needs good coupling to transfer the power, necessitating the magnetic core? The Rogowski being unloaded can get away with very poor coupling?!

Comment: That's reasoned OK.

Comment: `You could also not use a burden, and instead integrate the voltage.` Operation without a burden resistor will probably lead to core saturation.

Comment: That's possible. I forgot that a high current wire can also in practice have so high H around it that the iron core saturates without current in the secondary winding.

Answer (score 0):

> can I use one as the other by changing the circuit

Short answer is no.

A current transformer is, as you know, an ordinary transformer with 1-to-N turns ratio. The induced current is independent from geometry. Also, due its volt-seconds limitation, a random-value burden resistor cannot be used.

A Rogowski coil, on the other hand, generates "voltage" proportional to \$di/dt\$ as well as coil geometry.

Comment: So the difference is that CTs always have magnetizable cores and rogowskis don't? If not, then how is an air core CT actually different from a Rogowski in terms of construction?

Comment: @tobalt Not only that. Rogowski coils don't necessarily need a magnetic (ferrite, iron powder, etc) core, yes. But also the structure is totally different. My English is not enough to explain but I'll try: the wire is wound around a flexible material (e.g. plastic), and at one end the wire is run through the centre of the material back to the starting end. So both ends of the wire are located at the same end of the flexible material (Hope I could explain. And I don't know if there's any other methods.). I don't think you can have a CT in this kind of construction.

Comment: CTs are wound in the same way usually. Think of clamp on CT, their winding also extends around the braces/arms and then return to a common point where they are joint.

Comment: @tobalt in case of clamp-on CTs, yes. But the main point is still the requirement of a magnetic core. You can run a Rogowski coil open-circuited, but can't a CT because it'll saturate.

Comment: Oh it sure can. It could saturate, but we could make a larger airgap.. It could spark so let's keep the primary current or winding ratio low.. If you remove the burden, you will see the same V that is proportional to dI/dt hence my question. But I think, loser has answered it for me. 

Comment: @tobalt a larger airgap will store more energy which is a problem for resetting the core. Also the leakage will be higher therefore the bandwidth will be reduced. Yes, we can reduce the turns ratio but the practical point of a CT will be lost e.g. 5A to measure 15A.